# Algebra Polynomials Problem 1

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Assume that there is a polynomial $P(x)$

> $$ P(4) = P(5) = P(6) = \cdots = P(10) = 10! $$
>   $$ P(3) = 11! $$
>   $$ \deg(P(x)) = 7 $$

What is the constant term of polynomial $P(x)$?

The answer is

> $$ 1201\times 10! $$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**

---

We first shift your polynomial down by $10!$ to get a new polynomial $P^*$
$$P^*(4) = P^*(5) = P^*(6) = P^*(7)=P^*(8)=P^*(9)= P^*(10) = 0$$
We now have all $7$ roots of this polynomial, and *they are all zero*. Try to express your polynomial in terms of these roots.